# set UIImagePickerController frame size and location

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to set the frame of the UIImagePickerController to the middle of the screen like this in my OverlayViewController - a place where I created custom buttons:

```
self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] ==0)
{
   CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
   CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame)-self.view.frame.size.height-10.0, CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame), self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
   self.view.frame = newFrame;
   [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
   CGRect imagePickerControllerFrame = CGRectMake(0, topPanel.frame.size.height + 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - topPanel.frame.size.height - bottomPanel.frame.size.height);
   self.imagePickerController.view.frame = imagePickerControllerFrame;
}
```

However, it opens it full screen and the selected image includes the area below the top and bottom panels. I would like it to be a rectangle.

I present the `UIImagePickerController` from a delegate view like this:

```
[self presentViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `UIViewController` reference ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)):

> **presentViewController:animated:completion:**
>
> **Discussion**
>
> On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen

If you want to embed image picker, you should manually add its view to one of your other views.

Comment: How can I do the embedding with custom controller?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];`. Assuming, of course, that you have configured image picker's view's frame for your needs. That's an example, of course, I can't see your full code and I can't say where and how exactly embedding should be performed.

Comment: I actually have a custom layer on top of it. I will try to do it without it

Comment: will it work with custom controllers? I am creating an app similar to Instagram

Comment: Well, if you're dealing with views (or layers, doesn't really matter here), not controllers, then I assume yes, it will work well. Just add image picker's view directly to your custom controller's view. Don't release the imagePickerController itself though, if you need its delegate methods.

Comment: what do you mean by don't release the imagePickerController itself? of course I need its delegate methods like didFinish

Comment: But how can I release the imagePIckerController that was created in subview?